# Htaccess changes the content type of page?

Tags: java, .htaccess, utf-8, response, content-type

I have that code at my Java side:

```
....
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
....
```

I use Struts2, JSP and Java for my application over MySQL and Apache. When I write something to response object and check the content type at firebug it is always

```
charset=ISO-8859-1
```

So, when I want to writing something over response object there occurs unrecognized characters.

My jsp files has that line at first every time:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

I tested my program and when it works without passing over .htaccess everything is OK. I know that .htaccess changes the content type.

I tried something like here:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

However I am not sure do I miss something or try anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the encoding in your JSP page header, like this:

```
<%@ page session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting your character encoding using `response.setCharacterEncoding()`, why not just set the Content-Type without specifying charset?

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```